# what is equivalent to python with statement in dart

Tags: python, dart, telegram, with-statement

for example, when starting a telegram client using pyrogram library, one would do:

```
with Client as app:
  app.do_something()
```

There's already a tdlib package in dart although not like pyrogram.
any help about this topic is appreciated.

---

For those who know Dart but not Python, the `with` statement takes a *context manager* and executes some of its code before and after the body is executed. The above code is *very* roughly equivalent to

```
app = Client.__enter__()
app.do_something()
app.__exit__()
```

except that `app.__exit__()` is guaranteed to be called, even if `app.do_something()` raises an exception. `__enter__` and `__exit__` are the two methods defined by the type of `Client` that make it a context manager.

Comment: so, according to PEP 343. The ```with``` statement clarifies code that previously would use try...finally blocks to ensure that [clean-up code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_cleanup) is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct Dart equivalent to a Python `with` statement. However, you can use the following pattern to achieve the same behavior:

```dart
void clientScope(void Function(Client) callback) {
  // Initialize your client
  final client = Client.initialize();

  // Acts as the body of a 'with' statement
  callback(client);

  // Perform any cleanup
  client.cleanup();
}
```

Which could then be used in the following way:

```dart
clientScope((Client app) {
  app.doSomething();
});
```

For robustness, you could also wrap `callback` in a try-catch-finally and perform any cleanup in the finally block.